# PowerShell: How to Suppress script error in WPF WebBrowser?

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have implemented WPF Webbrowser in PowerShell. However, I am unable to suppress the script error.

Could you someone please guide how to suppress script error?

WPF XAML Code:

```
<Grid
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
          

    
            <DockPanel >
                <WebBrowser Name="WebBrowser" DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                </WebBrowser>
            </DockPanel>
    
        
    
</Grid>
```

[Error snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8nMP.png)

Comment: `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"`? `-ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"`?

Comment: Hi, I have tried it already. Not helpful. Please suggest whether is there any method or property to be configured on WebBrowser to suppress this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the Browser in Silent mode.

In C# it would be:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        wbMain.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(wbMain_Navigated);
    }

    void wbMain_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SetSilent(wbMain, true); // make it silent
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        wbMain.Navigate(new Uri("... some url..."));
    }
}


public static void SetSilent(WebBrowser browser, bool silent)
{
    if (browser == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("browser");

    // get an IWebBrowser2 from the document
    IOleServiceProvider sp = browser.Document as IOleServiceProvider;
    if (sp != null)
    {
        Guid IID_IWebBrowserApp = new Guid("0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
        Guid IID_IWebBrowser2 = new Guid("D30C1661-CDAF-11d0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E");

        object webBrowser;
        sp.QueryService(ref IID_IWebBrowserApp, ref IID_IWebBrowser2, out webBrowser);
        if (webBrowser != null)
        {
            webBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.PutDispProperty, null, webBrowser, new object[] { silent });
        }
    }
}


[ComImport, Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
private interface IOleServiceProvider
{
  [PreserveSig]
  int QueryService([In] ref Guid guidService, [In] ref Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] out object ppvObject);
}
```

If this dont help you, maybe you can use the Windows Forms Browser  and use the 2.0's WebBrowser property: SuppressScriptErrors.

Comment: I am not very expert in C#. Could you please suggest how to implement this code in PowerShell?